# python Matplotlib candlestick plot works only on daily data, not for intraday

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I'm trying to plot candlestick data using matplotlib. Starting from 1 minute data I group them using pd.Timegrouper in various time frame , from 5minute to daily, but plot only works on daily data. Below you can find a sample of the 1 minute data i'm using:

[image: **Data sample:** (pandas dataframe)]

```py
data_indexed_5M = data_indexed.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(freq=pd.offsets.Minute('5'))]).agg({'<LOW>': lambda s: s.min(), 
                                     '<HIGH>': lambda s: s.max(),
                                     '<OPEN>': lambda s: s[0],
                                     '<CLOSE>': lambda s: s[-1]})

ata_indexed_Daily = data_indexed.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D')]).agg({'<LOW>': lambda s: s.min(), 
                                     '<HIGH>': lambda s: s.max(),
                                     '<OPEN>': lambda s: s[0],
                                     '<CLOSE>': lambda s: s[-1]})

data_indexed_Daily['Date2'] = data_indexed_Daily['dateTime'].apply(lambda d: mdates.date2num(d.to_pydatetime()))
data_indexed_Daily = data_indexed_Daily.set_index('dateTime')

data_indexed_5M['Date2'] = data_indexed_5M['dateTime'].apply(lambda d: mdates.date2num(d.to_pydatetime()))
data_indexed_5M = data_indexed_5M.set_index('dateTime')


def plotWithMatplot(dataevento):
    deltatime = timedelta(minutes=100*5)  #...(days=100) for daily plot

    pre_data = dataevento - deltatime
    post_data= dataevento + deltatime

    data_slice = data_indexed_5M.loc[pre_data:post_data]   #data_indexed_Daily --> for daily plot

    tuples = [tuple(x) for x in     data_slice[['Date2','<OPEN>','<HIGH>','<LOW>','<CLOSE>']].values]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.xaxis_date()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:"))    

    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.xlabel("Date")
    plt.ylabel("Price")
    plt.title("EURUSD 5M")
    candlestick_ohlc(ax, tuples, width=.6, colorup='g', alpha =.4);

    plt.show()
```

but then when i plot same event on the Daily and 5 minute (ot any other intraday time frame) i obtain following results:

Daily (good result):

[image]

Intraday (bad result):

[image]

Comment: A possible solution can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846032/matplotlib-candlestick-intraday-chart-is-one-big-blob#):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the undocumented `width` argument to `candlestick_ohlc` is the key. Multiply it by the fraction of a day between each of your data points. Since your data is in minute increments, this should do:

```
candlestick_ohlc(ax, tuples, width=.6/(24*60), colorup='g', alpha =.4);
```

Note this turns out to be an FAQ, though the links are not obvious. See:

- [Charting Candlestick_OHLC one minute bars with Pandas and Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821916/charting-candlestick-ohlc-one-minute-bars-with-pandas-and-matplotlib)
- [Matplotlib Candlestick (Intraday) Chart is One Big Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846032/matplotlib-candlestick-intraday-chart-is-one-big-blob#)
- [Matplotlib candlestick in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081854/matplotlib-candlestick-in-minutes)