# Matplotlib Candlestick (Intraday) Chart is One Big Blob

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a Candlestick chart using Matplotlib with data I am acquiring for a REST API call. However since the call uses a unique access token I've downloaded a sample data and loaded it into a csv for the purposes of this question. [Here is a pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/3Z26y9dA) to what the sample data looks like. To process the data within Python I am using Pandas to create a data frames. Here is what my code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
from datetime import date

""" Pandas """
historic_df = pd.read_csv("sample_data.csv")

dates = pd.to_datetime(historic_df['time'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
openp = historic_df['openAsk']
highp =  historic_df['highAsk']
lowp =  historic_df['lowAsk']
closep =  historic_df['closeAsk']

""" Matplotlib """
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))

x = 0
ohlc = []

while x < len(dates):
    d = mdates.date2num(dates[x])
    append_me = d, openp.values[x], highp.values[x], lowp.values[x], closep.values[x]
    ohlc.append(append_me)
    x += 1

candlestick_ohlc(ax1, ohlc, width=0.4, colorup='#77d879', colordown='#db3f3f')
plt.show()
```

And here is what my output looks like:

[image]

You can sort of make out the vertical lines for the candlestick's, however the bars seems really wide. Any ideas on how I can solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Works fine on some Yahoo data (using daily data), please post your actual data.  All I did was change this line here: `dates = pd.to_datetime(historic_df['time'])` and it looks good.  For some reason it looks like you're trying to plot multiple days with every hour plotted on 1 chart which would explain the overlap...

Comment: I've included in my post a link to the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3Z26y9dA) with the data that was used to plot the chart that I've screenshotted. Not sure if it makes a difference but my data in intraday, so each entry is not a different day, but more like 5-10 seconds apart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your width on the chart and it will be fine:

`candlestick_ohlc(ax1, ohlc, width=0.001, colorup='#77d879', colordown='#db3f3f')`

Tested using your data and it looks good.

Comment: Yup that did it, is thee anyway I can have the width adjusted automatically, for when I load in daily, or less granular data?

Comment: A pr into mpl make the default width more intelligent would probably be accepted.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit late to respond, but can you elaborate on what you mean by pr?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the undocumented `width` argument to `candlestick_ohlc` is the key. Multiply it by the fraction of a day between each of your data points. Since your data is in minute increments, this should do:

```
candlestick_ohlc(ax, tuples, width=.6/(24*60), colorup='g', alpha =.4);
```

To automate, use the difference between dates of successive data points. For example:

```
width=0.6/(mdates.date2num(dates[1])-mdates.date2num(dates[0]))
```

Note this turns out to be an FAQ, though the links are not obvious. See:

- [Charting Candlestick_OHLC one minute bars with Pandas and Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821916/charting-candlestick-ohlc-one-minute-bars-with-pandas-and-matplotlib)
- [python Matplotlib candlestick plot works only on daily data, not for intraday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823880/python-matplotlib-candlestick-plot-works-only-on-daily-data-not-for-intraday/)
- [Matplotlib candlestick in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081854/matplotlib-candlestick-in-minutes)

Comment: Couldn't find anywhere the info on how to automate it - brilliant! Thanks a ton.